# Monitor a process on Windows 7

Tags: taskmanager, netstat, resource-monitor

What is the best way to monitor a process on Windows Machine?
I know we can use Resource Monitor but I find it difficult as I am trying to monitor CPU, Memory, Network, Threads for httpd processes (Apache) and these will be shut down and restarted often.
So, selecting all httpd processes in REsource Monitor is difficult as which ever gots killed is gone from selection and new started needs to be selected to show on the top of the list.
Any suggestions?  Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALL - sysinternals - (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795535)

CPU - "CPU-Z" (http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) - incl. some GPU support

Network - WireShark(https://www.wireshark.org/)

or

Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler2 - autoDL FYI)

Comment: PortMon in sysinternals is great for monitoring traffic, and all of the above are executable binaries so you could put them in your system startup so they launch @ startup. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike.  I am trying to figure out a simple way of viewing same data as in Task Manager (CPU, Working memory, threads, ..) or Resource Monitor on Windows but with the ability to filter by "httpd" processes (Apache processes).  Resource Monitor has nice display but httpd processes are constantly recycled so I have to look for new ones and check them off to show them at the top.